# SSIS Package with ODBC Source works when TargetServerVersion is 2017 but doesn't work when is 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, visual-studio-2019

we have a SSIS Package with a ODBC Source for extracting data from a DB2 data base. This package works perfectly in Visual Studio 2017 and TargetServerVersion SQL Server 2017. When we try to run this package in Visual Studio 2019 and TargetServerVersion SQL Server 2019 it fails.

Even if we create a SSIS project from scratch and try to use a ODBC Source to DB2 in VS2019 still fails.

We have tried some other things like change the Batch Size. Depend on the Source Table, if we set the Batch Size to 1 it works, but not with all tables. With the default Batch Size (1000), the Data Flow seems to work, but get a error message and the number of rows is not equal to the number of rows of the source table:
[image]

If we create a SSIS project in VS2019 but set TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2017, it works, but our production server is SQL Server 2019.

Visual Studio Info:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Versión 16.10.0
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.10.0+31321.278
Microsoft .NET Framework
Versión 4.8.04084

SQL Server Analysis Services 15.0.19526.0
Diseñador de Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
Versión 15.0.19526.0

SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.62105.04180
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.2000.166
Diseñador de MS SQL Server Integration Services
Versión 15.0.2000.166

SsmsVsIntegration 1.0

Any solution?

Thanks.

UPDATE with more info:

SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension version 3.13.1

DB2 data base (AS/400, version 7) and I'm using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver 13.00.01.00 (v7r2m0).

Comment: What is the error message you get? Regardless, it shouldn't matter if you deploy an 2017 targeted package to SQL Server 2019.

Comment: This is the only error message I get: "[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Origen ODBC returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure."

Comment: Please click on the status line text at the bottom, or on the *Progress* button in the top bar to get a detailed overview of the process steps and every info, warning and error that occurred.

Comment: I did it. That message is the only error or warning in the Progress section.

Comment: Since it seems to process most tables and records, it should only be related to data or permissions. I'd create an error output target (simply dump in a Derived Column) and enable the Data Viewer on the Error Pipeline. This should give you an idea which records are failing and maybe a clue why they could be failing.

Comment: Thanks @Filburt . I'll try, but I don't think that's the problem, because when I change the TargetServerVersion in Visual Studio, all work perfectly. In fact, all the components in the Data Flow ends with a green mark, even if I run the package targeted to 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved installing the latest version of the IBM i Access ODBC Driver: 13.64.25.00